# github updated file information

Tags: bash, github, sh, github-api

is there anyway to know if a file is changed on github to do some task on linux

changed=false;

changed = myAPP/res/values/strings.xml //get information if it is changed

if (changed) do somthing 
else
do something else

Answer (score 1):

Not without some work on your part.

GitHub has a concept called [hooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/). This allows you to set up a server that gets a notification when a GitHub has received a push to a repository.

You should then write a program to check if the file is changed and take the appropriate action.

Comment: Thank you, can we hook on a file too? I am looking on it in details.

Comment: Unfortunately, GitHub does not offer that granularity